Usage of verb + の + adjective here

やっぱり海外のドラマってスケール違うよな!


車めっちゃくちゃ爆発する！吹っ飛ぶの爽快

I understand the sentence is like "As I thought, oversea dramas are totally on a different scale. The car totally exploded! "
But then I'm stumbled on how to take 吹っ飛ぶの爽快 here? "A refreshing blow off"? The sentence doesn't end with a だ and it just ends like this (I guess the character is excited).

Side comment: I know this isn't the focus of your question, but do bear in mind that 海外【かいがい】 is a noun, referring to "overseas" as a place.

I mean isn't it just "foreign drama" basically?

In terms of meaning, yes.  海外のドラマ → literally "overseas's drama" → idiomatically "foreign drama, drama from overseas".

You can simply think it is an omission of だ.
The の is a nominalizer, and が (or は) is omitted.
Thus 吹っ飛ぶの爽快 can be understood as (車が)吹っ飛ぶの(が)爽快(だ) = Cars' blowing off is refreshing (putting aside if refreshing correctly translates 爽快だ).
Notes.

As for ending without だ, you can think it is a 体言止め. Strictly speaking 爽快 may not be a noun though.

I can't find similar questions, but omitting particle after nominalizing の should happen frequently enough in casual utterances.


People may say:

昼間からビール飲むの最高 Drinking beer during daytime is superb. (飲むのが/は)
(For example, as an answer to what did you eat for supper) 残り物をあっためたの食べた I ate the leftover that is warmed up (あっためたのを).

